# get Index from an Array using Express + GraphQL

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I am just getting my hands dirty with GraphQL using Express. I am following the [Academind YouTube Series for GraphQL-Express-Node-React](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL55RiY5tL51rG1x02Yyj93iypUuHYXcB_). I have just setup a basic GraphQL Schema where I have hardcoded Array of Strings which is returned. I want to create a Query which gives me the index of the element from this hardcoded array using GraphQL (`graphiql`)

### Code

```
const express = require('express'); // Add Express Module
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Add Body-Parser Middleware for JSON handling in Requests
const graphqlHttp = require('express-graphql'); // Add Middleware for GraphQL Resolvers over Express HTTP
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql'); // Javascript Object-Destructuring (pull objects from packages)

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // JSON parsing Middleware added

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHttp({
    schema: buildSchema(`
        type RootQuery {
            events: [String!]!
            getEventIndex(eventName: String): Int
        }

        type RootMutation {
            createEvent(name: String): String
        }

        schema {
            query: RootQuery
            mutation: RootMutation
        }
    `),
    rootValue: {
        events: () => {
            return ['Cooking', 'All-Night Coding', 'Romantic'];
        },
        getEventIndex: (args) => {
            const _arr = ['Cooking', 'All-Night Coding', 'Romantic'];
            const index = _arr.findIndex(args.eventName);
            return index;
        },
        createEvent: (args) => {
            const eventName = args.name; // same as that of the parameter for `createEvent`
            return eventName;

        }
    },
    graphiql: true
}));

app.listen(3000);
```

I created a query  `getEventIndex(eventName: String): Int` which takes in the event name and provides me the index (which is integer)

#### Result in `graphiql`

**query**

```
query {
  getEventIndex(eventName: "Cooking")
}
```

**result**

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cooking is not a function",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "getEventIndex"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "getEventIndex": null
  }
}
```

Why would `Cooking` here be considered as a `function` and not as an argument in `createEvent` mutation?

Of course I am jumping into GraphQL without much deep diving into its Specifications but I guess it might be capable of handling parameter based querying too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not specific to GraphQL.

[Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) expects a function to be passed in as its first parameter. The function is called for each element in the array until the function returns a truthy value, at which point it returns the index of that element. The value of `args.eventName` is not a function (it's a String) so you end up with that error.

Either pass it a function, like:

```
const index = _arr.findIndex(value => value === args.eventName)
```

or just use [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead, which is probably what you meant to do:

```
const index = _arr.indexOf(args.eventName)
```